# Как сделать выборку из базы, если имеется только название из столба name?

Tags: sql

Помогите, пожалуйста.
Как сделать выборку из базы, если имеется только название из столба name?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * from `table` where `name` = "value"
```

Где value - значение по столбцу name.

Если я вас правильно понял, конечно.

Если работаете с PHP, то попробуйте следующее

```
        try
    {   
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=хост базы;dbname=имя базы','пользователь','пароль');
    }
        catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die("Error: ".$e->getMessage());
    }

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from `table` where `name` = :value"); // имя таблицы своё подставьте.
$query-> bindParam(":value", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR); // Вместо $value - свою переменную.
$query->execute();

// Тут проверим, сколько затронули строк запросом
if ($query->rowCount() == 0){
// Если затронули 0 строк - выведем ошибку, которая не дала пройти запросу
print_r($query->errorinfo());
}else{
$query = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Если запрос затронул больше 0 строк - преобразовали ответ в ассоц. массив.
/*
Тут Ваш код, работайте с асс. массивом как Вам надо
*/
}
```

Где надо - подставьте свои значения

Comment: Вот и я так думал)), но так почему-то возвращает пустой результат

Comment: @bogdanbv обновил ответ.

Comment: c PHP не работаем, но все равно спасибо

Comment: @bogdanbv какой язык? 
Принудительно выведите дамп переменной, и посмотрите, что там

Comment: Я сделал немного по другому-
SELECT * FROM `ActionType` WHERE `name`like"%однозначение%второезначение%"